# Variation of Knapsack in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, solver, knapsack-problem

So, I need to find the total number of combinations for a list of 10 data points that add up to AT LEAST 100. All of the examples to solve this I've found only give the number of combinations that EQUAL a number. How can I total the combinations that are higher than 100? Is this doable without VBA in Excel?

Another idea was calculating the total number of combinations (10!) and subtracting those UNDER 1,000 to find the number. But again, how to find the total number of combinations falling in a range?

Problem statement: 10 data points (65, 52, 48, 44, 42, 41, 39, 38, 30, 18) How many combinations can total at least 100?

Sources I've tried (I can't post more than 2 links) 
http://www.tushar-mehta.com/excel/templates/match_values/index.html

[Find out which combinations of numbers in a set add up to a given total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989807/find-out-which-combinations-of-numbers-in-a-set-add-up-to-a-given-total)

Comment: Is it ***100*** or ***1000*** ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent it is 100. Sorry for the typo

Comment: *"calculating the total number of combinations (10!)"* ... The number of  possible subsets is actually `2^n`, not `n!`.

Answer (score 3):

1. Enter the 10 items in **A1** through **J1**
2. In **K1** enter the formula `=IF(ROW()<512,"0" & DEC2BIN(ROW(),9),"1" & DEC2BIN(ROW()-512,9))`
3. Copy row 1 down through row 1023
4. Copy column **K** and PasteSpecialValues into column **L**
5. Use TextToColumns to parse column **L** into columns **M** through **V**
6. In **W1** enter `=SUMPRODUCT((A1:J1)*(M1:V1))` and copy down

Column **W** contains the sums of all possible combinations.

Finally, in another cell, enter:

```
=COUNTIF(W:W,">=" & 100)
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To generate a ***36*** bit binary pattern, I use:

```
=DEC2BIN(INT(ROW()/2^27),9)&DEC2BIN(INT(MOD(ROW(),2^27)/2^18),9)&DEC2BIN(INT(MOD(ROW(),2^18)/2^9),9)&DEC2BIN(MOD(ROW(),2^9),9)
```

So for ***20*** bits, just use:

```
=RIGHT(DEC2BIN(INT(ROW()/2^27),9)&DEC2BIN(INT(MOD(ROW(),2^27)/2^18),9)&DEC2BIN(INT(MOD(ROW(),2^18)/2^9),9)&DEC2BIN(MOD(ROW(),2^9),9),20)
```

[image]

**EDIT#2:**

To do something like *TextToColumns* with VBA, select the cells and run this macro:

```
Sub PseudoTextToColumns()
    Dim r As Range, L As Long, i As Long, t As String
    For Each r In Selection
        t = r.Text
        L = Len(t)
        For i = 1 To L
            r.Offset(0, i).Value = Mid(t, i, 1)
        Next i
    Next r
End Sub
```

***NOTE:***

This will not work for 21 items.

Comment: Nice (+1) Excel 2013 has a `BITAND` function that could be used to get the bits without quite so much fuss (I think -- I'm still stuck with Excel 2010 so can't test it)

Comment: Nice, +1 too!. I changed my routine below to be a UDF, so that it would be curious to try it with a formula in `X1`: `=CombinationsByBruteForce(A1:J1, 100)`... It should yield the same result ;)

Comment: Notice it is still a brute force approach, kind of doing the same thing in VBA or using Excel formulas: examining all possible combinations.

Comment: @A.S.H  I agree completely

Comment: anyway to do this in Solver to give same result?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent the next part of the problem asks to do this same thing with 20 data points. It looks like this method won't work with so many?

Comment: @JoeJohnson  You would need to modify the column **K** formula to generate 20 bits, etc.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent what is the VBA code for this text2columns macro?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent here is what i modified it to, but i get the #NUM! error

Comment: @Gary'sStudent =IF(ROW()<524288,"0" & DEC2BIN(ROW(),19),"1" & DEC2BIN(ROW()-524288,19))

Comment: @JoeJohnson  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: thanks @Gary'sStudent - last thing, can you share the code for the VBA Macro to do the textToColumns?

Comment: @JoeJohnson  See mt **EDIT#2**

Answer (score 1):

**VBA Brute Force solution**

I would share the following *brute force* solution that checks all possible combinations. It is fast enough on small arrays up to 15 entries or so. It solves your problem and you can take it as a model for any brute computation and also as a starting point to optimize and apply faster algorithms. It can also be a good basis for testing any optimized algorithm that you might implement later.

```
Option Explicit

' Main function. Computes the all combinations and prints those that exceed the target
' Each combination is specified by a mask of bits that specifies whether to take o to leave the entry
Function CombinationsByBruteForce(inputArray() As Double, target As Double) As Long
  Dim mask As Long, count As Long
  For mask = 1 To 2 ^ (1 + UBound(inputArray)) - 1
    If SumByMask(inputArray, mask) > target Then
      count = count + 1
      PrintByMask inputArray, mask
    End If
  Next
  Debug.Print "Total number of successful combinations: " & count
  CombinationsByBruteForce = count
End Function

' computes the sum for a given combination.  The combination is specified by a mask of bits
' that tells which entries belong to the combination (the 1 bits)
Function SumByMask(inputArray() As Double, mask As Long) As Double
  Dim bit As Long
  For bit = 0 To UBound(inputArray)
    If (mask And (2 ^ bit)) <> 0 Then SumByMask = SumByMask + inputArray(bit)
  Next
End Function

' Prints out the entries belonging to a combination specified by a mask
Sub PrintByMask(inputArray() As Double, mask As Long)
  Dim bit As Long
  For bit = 0 To UBound(inputArray)
    If (mask And (2 ^ bit)) <> 0 Then Debug.Print inputArray(bit),
  Next
  Debug.Print
End Sub
```

---

```
' For testing. An array of doubles and a target are specified.
' The variant array is copied into a Double array to improve speed
Sub testing()
  Dim target As Double: target = 350   ' target number to exceed
  Dim test: test = Array(65, 52, 48, 44, 42, 41, 39, 38, 30, 18)

  'convert to explicit array of Double
  ReDim inputArray(UBound(test)) As Double
  Dim i As Long
  For i = LBound(test) To UBound(test): inputArray(i) = test(i): Next

  ' Launsh the brute force computation
  CombinationsByBruteForce inputArray, target
End Sub
```

**Output** for the above test:

> ```
>  65          52  48          44   42          41  39          38  
>  65          52  48          44   42          41  39          30  
>  65          52  48          44   42          41  38          30  
>  65          52  48          44   42          39  38          30  
>  65          52  48          44   41          39  38          30  
>  65          52  48          42   41          39  38          30  
>  65          52  44          42   41          39  38          30  
>  65          52  48          44   42          41  39          38   30         
>  65          52  48          44   42          41  39          38   18         
>  65          52  48          44   42          41  39          30   18         
>  65          52  48          44   42          41  38          30   18         
>  65          52  48          44   42          39  38          30   18         
>  65          52  48          44   41          39  38          30   18         
>  65          52  48          42   41          39  38          30   18         
>  65          52  44          42   41          39  38          30   18         
>  65          48  44          42   41          39  38          30   18         
>  52          48  44          42   41          39  38          30   18         
>  65          52  48          44   42          41  39          38   30          18  
> Total number of successful combinations: 18
> ```

As an entry point for solving with the solver, you can try a `BIP` model, where the decision variables are the bits of the mask. The solver should then apply some *branch and bound* or similar technique to find a combination. But to print out all the successful combinations with the solver seems much more difficult to solve with the solver, because it is not an optimization problem.